# Error when doing a getdescriptorinfo on a Miniscript descriptor (V24.0.1)

Tags: bitcoin-core, output-script-descriptors, miniscript

I'm trying to play around with miniscript and import them into Bitcoin Core v24.0.1.
I created the following descriptor in https://miniscript.fun  and tried to validate it in Bitcoin Core

```
bitcoin-cli getdescriptorinfo "wsh(thresh(2,nl:older(12960),s:pk(038b4059419fe3b95acdee6aff2f9afdca87231d14bd2cbcd3367b11d9d819a71d),s:pk([c893176c/48'/0'/0'/2']xpub6EpqBFyJW2qiEmgcYZqwEGCRuQh3y9fY72RWeAG7pNvKJWgnx7mkviWtfsF7VNQhWPx43zzNfkWhoF8RcnP2KKsXbNHrFNdzx8MFy83N5Sq/0/*)))#925wgae2"
```

However, I get the following error:

> A function is needed within P2WSH

Where did I go wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your descriptor (including the Miniscript) is valid. I think you are getting this error because you used an `xpub` (mainnet encoding of an extended public key) on a testnet node.

On a mainnet node:

```
$ bitcoin-cli getdescriptorinfo "wsh(thresh(2,nl:older(12960),s:pk(038b4059419fe3b95acdee6aff2f9afdca87231d14bd2cbcd3367b11d9d819a71d),s:pk([c893176c/48'/0'/0'/2']xpub6EpqBFyJW2qiEmgcYZqwEGCRuQh3y9fY72RWeAG7pNvKJWgnx7mkviWtfsF7VNQhWPx43zzNfkWhoF8RcnP2KKsXbNHrFNdzx8MFy83N5Sq/0/*)))#925wgae2"
{
  "descriptor": "wsh(thresh(2,nl:older(12960),s:pk(038b4059419fe3b95acdee6aff2f9afdca87231d14bd2cbcd3367b11d9d819a71d),s:pk([c893176c/48'/0'/0'/2']xpub6EpqBFyJW2qiEmgcYZqwEGCRuQh3y9fY72RWeAG7pNvKJWgnx7mkviWtfsF7VNQhWPx43zzNfkWhoF8RcnP2KKsXbNHrFNdzx8MFy83N5Sq/0/*)))#925wgae2",
  "checksum": "925wgae2",
  "isrange": true,
  "issolvable": false,
  "hasprivatekeys": false
}
```

On a regtest node (converting the `xpub` to a `tpub`):

```
$ bitcoin-cli -regtest getdescriptorinfo "wsh(thresh(2,nl:older(12960),s:pk(038b4059419fe3b95acdee6aff2f9afdca87231d14bd2cbcd3367b11d9d819a71d),s:pk([c893176c/48'/0'/0'/2']tpubDFCThVnzDJoAWZsTzkq2SBXoEXnhxYAbef1oziKGAHgD3oMW2Lcr5ABiuuKu1sMwJJUxfaWFCrLkVRd31eEGCmKpey39vuJEY5wfj84sNhm/0/*)))#qxjqansp"
{
  "descriptor": "wsh(thresh(2,nl:older(12960),s:pk(038b4059419fe3b95acdee6aff2f9afdca87231d14bd2cbcd3367b11d9d819a71d),s:pk([c893176c/48'/0'/0'/2']tpubDFCThVnzDJoAWZsTzkq2SBXoEXnhxYAbef1oziKGAHgD3oMW2Lcr5ABiuuKu1sMwJJUxfaWFCrLkVRd31eEGCmKpey39vuJEY5wfj84sNhm/0/*)))#qxjqansp",
  "checksum": "qxjqansp",
  "isrange": true,
  "issolvable": false,
  "hasprivatekeys": false
}
```

Comment: This was absolutely the reason. Thank you Antoine!